# Possible to create a fixed-width drawable in XML?

Tags: android, drawable, xml-drawable, layer-list

I'm trying to simplify some graphics from requiring a 9-patch for each density, to just using an XML drawable. It's a fairly simple graphic:

[image: 9-patch drawable]

2 Segments:

- 8dp wide for both segments
- Top segment is 2dp tall
- Bottom segment fills the view
- Right side is filled with transparency

Giving this result when set as a background image:

[image: 9-patch as list item example]

It seems like this should be fairly simple to recreate as an XML drawable, and would avoid creating 5 different 9-patch graphics. However, I've looked into layer-list drawables, inset drawables, clip drawables -- they all seem to require that you know the size of the view beforehand (e.g. to keep it 2dp for an inset, you'd need to set `insetRight` to the width of the view - 2dp). I also tried using the `shape` tag's `size` tag, but that doesn't keep a fixed size, just a fixed proportion (so for taller views it will scale proportionally).

Am I overlooking something simple, or is this something I'd have to resort to checking programatically after layout?

Comment: Are you trying the background drawable for the TextView on each of the items?  Sorry, ignore this comment @kcoppock, I see you responded to my answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. This is the best solution I found. Only xml, no coding, no bitmaps, no additional views )

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid
            android:color="#ff0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:top="4dp">
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid
            android:color="#00ff00" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="10dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item> 
</layer-list>
```

[image]

Via code you can make your own drawble type with desired behavior. Xml drawable very limited. IMHO my suggestion is the closest to what you demanded.

Comment: This works if the last item has a solid color as the background. It will not work if it's supposed to be transparent(as it seems to be requested in the question).

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer by @Leonidos is very close to what I'm proposing, except I'm using the drawable as a separate view instead of the background for the entire list detail layout.  This allows it to be a fixed width and to let the item text have its own background.  Let me know if I'm not understanding your constraints.

The following file is "res/drawable/list_left_border"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#e76e63" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#ffc257" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then on the layout for the list item in "res/layout/list_item.xml"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:background="@drawable/list_left_border"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listItemText"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the image.  The background is pink to show that the list item is transparent.

[image]

Comment: additional views is cheating )

Comment: @Leonidos Is the constraint that the drawable should be the background of the layout for the entire detail item?  In my example that would be the LinearLayout view.  Or would it need to be the background of the TextView?

Comment: I mean that the author doesn't want additional views )

Comment: @Leonidos Agreed, it would be better to not have additional views -- however, this might still be a good solution. I think both of your solutions seems pretty clever and workable, but admittedly it would be preferable that the drawable is simply the background of the list item (LinearLayout or whatever it may be) as the view will actually be resized. Thank you both for the answers -- I'm going to wait a bit longer to accept either to see if any other solutions are proposed. :)

Comment: An improvement to this would be to use `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/list_left_border"` on the `TextView`. Then you can drop the extra `View`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go one further and suggest a slight reworking of AndroidGuy's answer, which itself includes Leonidos' answer.

Same drawable XML, different list item XML as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/list_left_border" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item Text"
        android:textSize="22sp" >
    </TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The FrameLayout gives the original background behaviour, rather than separation into a new view.

I've shown this below, with backgrounds to demonstrate:

[image: illustration]

This doesn't really deserve the points though.